# How to Execute a Batch Update in Snowflake JDBC

Tags: jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to execute a snowflake batch update on a PreparedStatement with no luck.  I'm able to execute each individual query (preparedStatement.executeQuery()) so the queries work.  But once I switch to a batchUpdate(), I'm getting an exception that seems like it isn't setting my variables (being thrown at insertEventStatement.executeBatch()).

```
net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 134
Bind variable ? not set.
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeUtil.checkErrorAndThrowException(SnowflakeUtil.java:88)
at net.snowflake.client.core.StmtUtil.execute(StmtUtil.java:384)
at net.snowflake.client.core.SFStatement.executeHelper(SFStatement.java:421)
at net.snowflake.client.core.SFStatement.executeQueryInternal(SFStatement.java:240)
at net.snowflake.client.core.SFStatement.executeQuery(SFStatement.java:180)
at net.snowflake.client.core.SFStatement.executeQuery(SFStatement.java:152)
at net.snowflake.client.core.SFStatement.execute(SFStatement.java:637)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeStatementV1.executeUpdateInternal(SnowflakeStatementV1.java:135)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakePreparedStatementV1.executeBatch(SnowflakePreparedStatementV1.java:1045)
```

Does anybody see what I might be missing?

```
public void insertBotEvents(List<SnowflakeRecord> snowflakeRecords) throws SQLException
{
    try
    {
        PreparedStatement insertEventStatement = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_EVENT);
        PreparedStatement insertMetaEventStatement = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_META_EVENT);
        for (SnowflakeRecord snowflakeRecord : snowflakeRecords)
        {
            insertEventStatement.setString(1, snowflakeRecord.getUserId());
            insertEventStatement.setString(2, snowflakeRecord.getSessionId());
            insertEventStatement.setString(3, snowflakeRecord.getEventTime().toString());
            insertEventStatement.setString(4, snowflakeRecord.getEventType());
            insertEventStatement.setString(5, snowflakeRecord.getEventValue());
            insertEventStatement.setString(6, snowflakeRecord.getAdditionalInfo());
            insertEventStatement.setString(7, snowflakeRecord.getAffiliateName());

            System.out.println("\nINSERTING NEW RECORD: \n" + snowflakeRecord);

            insertEventStatement.addBatch();

            if (snowflakeRecord.getSmVuiEventDto() != null && snowflakeRecord.getSmVuiEventDto().getParameters() != null)
            {
                for (ParametersDto parametersDto : snowflakeRecord.getSmVuiEventDto().getParameters())
                {

                    insertMetaEventStatement.setString(1, snowflakeRecord.getSmVuiEventDto().getName());
                    insertMetaEventStatement.setString(2, parametersDto.getName());
                    insertMetaEventStatement.setString(3, parametersDto.getValue());
                    insertMetaEventStatement.setString(4, snowflakeRecord.getUserId());
                    insertMetaEventStatement.setString(5, snowflakeRecord.getSessionId());
                    insertMetaEventStatement.setString(6, snowflakeRecord.getEventTime().toString());
                    insertMetaEventStatement.setString(7, snowflakeRecord.getEventType());
                    insertMetaEventStatement.setString(8, snowflakeRecord.getEventValue());
                    insertMetaEventStatement.setString(9, snowflakeRecord.getAdditionalInfo());

                    insertMetaEventStatement.addBatch();
                }
            }
        }
        insertEventStatement.executeBatch();
        insertMetaEventStatement.executeBatch();
        System.out.println("\nCommitting changes to snowflake.");
        connection.commit();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        connection.rollback();
        System.err.println("Unable to execute SQL. Rolling back snowflake import");
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }

}
```

Here are the queries:

```
private static final String INSERT_EVENT =
        "INSERT INTO EVENT " +
                "(USER_ID, " +
                " SESSION_ID, " +
                " EVENT_DATETIME, " +
                " EVENT_TYPE, " +
                " EVENT_VALUE, " +
                " ADDITIONAL_INFO, " +
                " AFFILIATE_ID " +
                ") " +
                "SELECT " +
                " ?, " +
                " ?, " +
                " ?, " +
                " ?, " +
                " ?, " +
                " ?, " +
                " AFFILIATE_ID " +
                "FROM AFFILIATE_LOOKUP " +
                "WHERE AFFILIATE_NAME = ?";

private static final String INSERT_META_EVENT =
        "INSERT INTO EVENT_META " +
        "(EVENT_ID, " +
        "   META_TYPE, " +
        "   META_NAME, " +
        "   META_VALUE " +
        ") " +
        "SELECT EVENT_ID, ?, ?, ? " +
        "FROM SM_VUI_EVENT " +
        "WHERE USER_ID=? AND " +
        "   SESSION_ID=? AND " +
        "   EVENT_DATETIME=? AND " +
        "   EVENT_TYPE=? AND " +
        "   EVENT_VALUE=? AND " +
        "   ADDITIONAL_INFO=?";
```

Edit: Apparently, it wasn't available in the JDBC version I was using (3.0.18) but was added in a recently release ([3.0.21](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/release-notes/2017-06.html#snowflake-jdbc-driver-v3-0-21-support-for-batch-updates)).  I will update this further if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Just confirmed that Snowflake currently don't support providing an array of bind within an INSERT statement containing subquery, but we are working on it.

Comment: Thanks for info. Do you know when that's scheduled to release? I currently don't have much data being sent. But, I'm expecting a large amount of data soon and based on the tests I've run it won't be feasible to execute the queries individually.  Or is there a better way for me to upload this data?

Comment: It should be released next week. However, the implementation is still client side loop and execute the query individually. If you want to load large amount of data, you should consider copy command.

Answer (score 1):

From a quick eyeball, I did not find anything wrong. Can you contact Snowflake Support and provide your JDBC logs in tracing?

If you don't know how to enable logging, refer to https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/jdbc-configure.html#configuring-logging.

Also if you can provide your the query id, I can take a quick look.